# How to use recursive_directory_iterator(..) without exceptions in C++

Tags: c++, exception, c++17

I use [recursive_directory_iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/recursive_directory_iterator) to iterate through directories. The iterator seems to throw exceptions when the passed path does not exist. Is there a way to use the iterator without enabling exceptions?

```cpp
// try / catch can't be used here
for (auto const& dir_entry : fs::recursive_directory_iterator("I-dont-exist"))
{
    std::cout << dir_entry << '\n';
}
```

Comment: [Use constructor (6)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/recursive_directory_iterator/recursive_directory_iterator).  That constructor will only throw `std::bad_alloc` if your machine has no available memory.

Comment: @DrewDormann I am blind, thanks so much!! I could accept this as an answer

Answer (score 1):

From [cppreference.com's writeup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/recursive_directory_iterator/recursive_directory_iterator):

> The overload taking a std::error_code& parameter sets it
> to the OS API error code if an OS API call fails, and executes ec.clear()
> if no errors occur.

The reason why this constructor is not marked `noexcept` is most likely because, pedantically, it might throw an exception for reasons unrelated to a nonexistent directory or path. This only guarantees no exceptions in case of filesystem issues, such as your nonexistent directory. Since you are looking to prevent exceptions getting thrown for that reason, this should work.

Your next task is to construct `std::filesystem::path` without throwing an exception.

`std::filesystem::path` constructors are defined as follows: "May throw implementation-defined exceptions", a carte-blanche for throwing an exception if they fancy to, for any reason.

But, practically, this is referring to filesystem paths that are, well, valid paths. Attempting to construct a path for "/:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM" on MS-Windows will likely earn you one of those "implementation-defined" exceptions.

If you feed a path string that's a valid path string, on your operating system, you're not going to get a thrown exception.

Finally, `std::filesystem::path`'s constructors are implicit. Avoiding exceptions, for your use case, boils down to:

1. Passing a valid path when constructing a recursive directory iterator. It's up to you to validate it according to your operating system filenames' rules.
2. Using the overload that takes a reference to an error code object, as an additional parameter.

Comment: Thanks so much for the insights and your detailed reply, that is super helpful! On the note of point 1, I need to avoid a TOCTOU race condition and therefore can't check if the path exists before. As Drew mentioned, there is a constructor (6) which takes a std::error_code that substitutes a noexcept version.

Comment: By "valid path" I meant "syntactically valid", not that it exists, or not. See my reference to a path called "/:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM".

Comment: Note that the iterator's `operator++` also throws on error, so you have to use its `increment(std::error_code&)` method instead, which means you can't use a `range-for` loop in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that either of the previous answers address the problem.

The issue is that the range-based for loop implicitly uses operator++() to increment the iterator. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for

However, if you want the non-throwing iterator, the signature is

`recursive_directory_iterator& increment( std::error_code& ec );`

(see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/recursive_directory_iterator/increment).

That means that you need to write an old-fashioned for loop.

Something like this

```
  std::error_code ec;
  using recursive_directory_iter =
      std::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator;
  auto dirEntry = std::filesystem::begin(recursive_directory_iter(dir, ec));
  for ( ; dirEntry != std::filesystem::end(recursive_directory_iter(dir, ec)); dirEntry.increment(ec)) {
```